# Library not initialized in Python (pygame)

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, initialization

so I have a font that I create in a class function.
I called this function many times in the code and it works perfectly, but one time when I call it it says:

```
self.font = pygame.font.Font( None, self.text_size )
RuntimeError: Library not initialized
```

I couldn't fix it! so a line before the *self.font* line I did **pygame.init()**

And still the same thing.. WTF

Help please, thanks.

Comment: Is there really nothing in the code where that line is that's different from the other calls? I imagine there must be something..

Comment: Nothing at all, I fixed it by taking parameters into **self.** and used them after that..

Comment: Please provide an answer to the question if you've fixed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I fixed it.

The line:

```
self.font = pygame.font.Font( None, self.text_size )
```

Was in a new Thread, therefore the libraries wasn't recognized

So I got the font and made the label in the **__*init*__** function and made them as self.
after that I could use them in the Thread without a problem, because I took the font - made it as a surface (**Font.render**) and used.